# Fix a div to the top of a page under the boostrap nav bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

Basically I am trying fix a header area to the top of all pages that require a header. The idea is to use a div with a class that can be applied when needed.

I have attempted a basic fixed div, however I always end up with it overlapping the content. Can anyone explain/show some css to float a div at the top of the body pushing all content down.

It should also be fixed, so scrolling would only affect content below.

My attempts have left me with the following:

[image]

As you can see the Applications title overlaps the table, when all other content should be floated down.

Answer (score 0):

You would apply fixed positioning to the div in question, then add `padding-top` to the body to push it down from the top. [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) achieves this affect by adding padding-top to the body element for the `navbar` component in combination with the `.navbar-fixed-top` CSS class. Otherwise you can apply `padding-top` or relative positioning `position: relative;` to the content element.

```
.topbar-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%
}

.body {
    padding-top: 50px; /* height of fixed bar */
}

/* OR */

.content-element {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the below code you can fix navbar to top.

HTML

```
<nav id="header" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div id="header-container" class="container navbar-container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a id="brand" class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container -->
        </nav><!-- /.navbar -->
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Prevent scroll on narrow devices */
}
body {
    padding-top: 100px;
}
footer {
    padding: 30px 0;
}
```